# Java inheritance; passing a subclass to an abstract method of a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract

Sorry for the title, couldn't come up with anything clearer.
I have the following structure:

```
public interface Vehicle {...}
public class Car implements Vehicle {...}
```

then:

```
public abstract class Fixer {
...
   abstract void fix(Vehicle vehicle);
...
}
```

and would like to have:

```
public class CarFixer extends Fixer {
    void fix(Car car) {...}
}
```

but this doesn't work. Eclipse says: `The type CarFixer must implement the inherited abstract method Fixer.fix(Vehicle)`. Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: That's because Eclipse is right. An overload isn't an override. Consider a generic `Fixer` class, perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Generics to solve this:

```
public abstract class Fixer<T extends Vehicle> {
    abstract void fix(T vehicle);
}

public class CarFixer extends Fixer<Car> {
    void fix(Car car) {...}
}
```

The problem with your original version is that the `fix` method allows any type of vehicle, but your implementing class allows only cars. Consider this code:

```
Fixer fixer = new CarFixer();
fixer.fix(new Bike()); // <-- boom, `ClassCastException`, Bike is a vehicle but not a car
```

Answer (score 3):

You've met the humble home of [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

Generics provide kind of *'wildcard'* type where a class or method can specify that *'we don't really care what type it is, we just need -a- type'*.

**Generics allow a *super* class to enforce a specific type in a *child* class instead of allowing *any* class that extends a certain class.**

This means that you're ultimately enforcing a new *highest allowed super-class* as the parameter (i.e. `Vehicle` is no longer the most basic allowable type you can pass to `fix()`; it's now whatever the subclass says it is, so long as that arbitrary type extends `Vehicle`).

Common places for generics are [container classes](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/hellofadude/archive/2014/02/12/overview-javas-container-classes) (i.e. `List`, `Map`, and `Set`) where the container doesn't really care about what type it tracks, but rather focuses on actually tracking and managing those instances.

Generics consist of one or more type placeholders (in Java, `E` and `T` are commonly used but the name doesn't really matter; they usually follow the normal type naming conventions) that are used in place of a specific class or super class.

---

In your code, you want subclasses to implement methods given their exact relevant types (i.e. a `CarFixer` would take `Car`s, a `JetpackFixer` would take `Jetpack`s) but you want to enforce that these types extend `Vehicle`.

In order to enforce this, you have to tell the `Fixer` class exactly what your subclass wants.

```
public abstract class Fixer <E extends Vehicle>
{
    abstract void fix(E vehicle);
}
```

Your subclass then extends Fixer, filling in `E` with the type it wants.

```
public class CarFixer extends Fixer<Car>
{
    @Override
    void fix(Car vehicle)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```